# Not able to Save Spark Dataframe as Table In HDP 3.0

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hdp

I have one dataframe I'm trying to save it as my hive table. I have tried all possible way but not able to save it as table in HDP 3.0. I am using below code.

```
    var sparksession =  SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("appname")
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition",  "true")
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode",   "nonstrict")
    .config("spark.sql.sources.maxConcurrentWrites","1")
    .config("hive.support.concurrency", "true")
    .config("parquet.compression", "SNAPPY")
    .config("parquet.enable.dictionary", "false")
    .config("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "snappy")
    .config("hive.mapred.mode", "nonstrict")
    .config("spark.sql.hive.hiveserver2.jdbc.url","url")
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate()

    val hive = com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseBuilder.session(sparksession).build()
    hive.setDatabase("testdb")
    val d1="select id,name,salary,city from testdb.test";
    val d2=hive.executeQuery(d1)
    d2.show //showing hive table's data.

    d2.write.format("orc").mode("append").saveAsTable("testdb.test_2")
  //test_2 table is already  created in testdb database.
    //but here getting error 'testdb' not found

    d2.write.format("orc").mode("append").saveAsTable("default.test_2")

    //if am using default then its not giving any error but saving data in 
    spark metadata not as a hive table.
    //same code is working fine in cloudera and am am getting data 
    in hive table but in hdp it's giving error.
```

I have tried save() methods also its working for partition table but i am not able to use bucket by while using save method.
can anyone please suggest me how should i save this dataframe directly into hive table in HDP 3.0.(Table is bucketed so can't use save method)

Comment: whats the error ?

Comment: @QuickSilver Database not found.

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the default database of hive connection to `testdb` via
`hive.setDatabase("testdb")`
then you should access all the tables in it directly w/o database 
e.g. `test_2` instead of `testdb.test_2`

Comment: Tried that also...but while writing am getting this issue i am able read tables w/o database name. when i m using saveAsTable method by default it is taking spark metadata.